# updating variable changes in components from a service with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

My app has a NameService which holds the name.

There are two child components of App, Navbar and TheContent which reference this service. Whenever the name changes in the service, i want it to update in both of the other components. How can i do this?

```ts
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

// Name Service

@Injectable()
class NameService {
  name: any;
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jack";
  }
  change(){
    this.name = "Jane";
  }
}

// The navbar
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: '<div>This is the navbar, user name is {{name}}.</div>'
})
export class Navbar {
  name: any;
  constructor(nameService: NameService) {
    this.name = nameService.name;
  }
}

// The content area
@Component({
  selector: 'thecontent',
  template: '<div>This is the content area. Hello user {{name}}. <button (click)=changeMyName()>Change the name</button></div>'
})
export class TheContent {

  name: any;

  constructor(public nameService: NameService) {
    this.name = nameService.name;
  }
  changeMyName() {
       this.nameService.change();
     console.log(this.nameService.name);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [NameService],
  directives: [TheContent, Navbar],
  template: '<navbar></navbar><thecontent></thecontent>'
})
export class App {
  constructor(public nameService: NameService) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 113):

Provide an event in the service and subscribe to it in the components:

```ts
@Injectable()
class NameService {
  name: any;
  // EventEmitter should not be used this way - only for `@Output()`s
  //nameChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  nameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jack";
  }
  change(){
    this.name = 'Jane';
    this.nameChange.next(this.name);
  }
}
```

```ts
export class SomeComponent { 
  constructor(private nameService: NameService) {
    this.name = nameService.name;
    this._subscription = nameService.nameChange.subscribe((value) => { 
      this.name = value; 
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   //prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

See also
[angular.io - COMPONENT INTERACTION - Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Comment: Also remember to unsubscribe from the event in the component else, the component instance will not be released. Need to call unsubscribe on the object returned by subscribe function.

Comment: @Chandermani Can you give ma a hint about how this is done in TS?

Comment: `let subscription=nameService.nameChange.subscribe((value) => { this.name = value; });  subscription.unsubscribe()`. I have faced this issue hence the disclaimer. If subscription has to cancelled from other method, the variable should be class level

Comment: @Chandermani thanks a lot for the hint about unsubscribing and also about the TS guidance ;-)

Comment: Yes @MarkRajcok i meant the same, instance variable.

Comment: @Chandermani, thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something before I edited the answer.

Comment: `Günter Zöchbauer` : This approach or above answer of `hansmaad` works well. But In real world application when user refresh the page, will it work? I think no because nameService will get initialized again and again 'Jack' name will appear. Any solution from your end?

Comment: @micronyks The question was not about keeping the value when reloaded IMHO. For this you need to persist the data to a server and reload it or at least use localstorage, to store it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question but soon gonna raise a new question once practically go through it.

Comment: This answer should be selected. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I've been try to implement this solution, but I get an error in the service that says `property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'`. Am I missing something in the above solution? Is there a working Plunkr of this solution?

Comment: @SteveSchrab

I had the same issue. It seems that the rxjs/Subject library has changed the method from emit to add. If you use add then everyting is working fine.

Comment: It should be `next` instead of `emit`. I mixed it up with `EventEmitter` I guess.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer

yes you are right, i also mixed it up it is next instead of add ;)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why is the ngOnDestroy necessary here ?

Comment: @Scipion In general, if you subscribe imperatively you should unsibscribe imperatively as well. In this case the component that subscribes to this service would probably still execute the callback passed to `subscribe()` on name change, even when it is already destroyed because the subscription stays active until the component gets garbage collected, which probably won't happen until the subscription is cancelled.

Comment: hmm! where did you implement ngOnDestroy?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did this `unsubscribe` will reflect in all other components also ?

Comment: @k11k2 not sure why you would think that. It only unsubscribes exactly this one subscription created with `subscribe(...)` a few lines above.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in my case,  it reflecting every where.

Comment: Sorry, can't imagine what that means without seeing the code. I'd suggest you create a new question.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why Angular has moved in this direction? I've recently returned to Angular, last time I used it was Angularjs. The best part of Angularjs IMO was the power of data binding, but I feel like as I'm using it now I have to constantly define inputs and outputs, manually emit changes everywhere they happen, unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks, etc. I used to just define something in a service or controller and it would update automatically everywhere. Things like .watch were a godsend. It's all gone now and unless I'm missing something big I feel like this is a step backwards.

Comment: @ryanovas AFAIK the power of Angularjs' databinding was the main reason they built a different Angular from scratch. It was inefficient and error-prone and circular dependencies could cause endess loops and it was difficult to debug when something went wrong. The new Angular gives more power to the developer but it requires a bit more boilerplate.

Answer (score 23):

Since `name` in `NameService` is a primitive type, you'll get different instance in the service and your components. When you change `name` in `NameService`, the component properties still have the initial value and the binding doesn't work as expected.

You should apply the angular1 "dot rule" here and bind to a reference type. Change `NameService` to store an object that contains the name.

```
export interface Info {
   name:string;
}

@Injectable()
class NameService {
  info: Info = { name : "Jack" };
  change(){
    this.info.name = "Jane";
  }
}
```

You can bind to this object and get updates to the `name` property automatically.

```
// The navbar
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: '<div>This is the navbar, user name is {{info.name}}.</div>'
})
export class Navbar {
  info: Info;
  constructor(nameService: NameService) {
    this.info = nameService.info;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it too. In angular 1 "always have a dot in your model" is a good way to reduce the effort to sync your bindings, it may be appropriate in Angular2 as well, depending on the use case.  Without it, using event emitters to sync the model can get tedious.

Comment: wow, why does this work compared to the EventEmitter way? it feels like so much less work?

Comment: Does it update Navbar view? Please look at here [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4TwpyQs9QuIPB68XyCQ?p=preview). Once you click on the button how would it update navbar view?

Comment: This is done through your suggested way. still its not updating Navbar view. According to your suggestion I guess object's name value will be changed but it will not be updated in view. Isn't it? Guide me if I'm wrong. Please temper my plnkr and answer me.

Comment: @micronyks In angular2 you can have multiple service instances. You should not define `providers` on both components. This way each component has its own `NameService`  http://plnkr.co/edit/nScZgT1hsIKHZ7Z5E6u3?p=preview

Comment: @BHull, it works because with an object, both the service and the component refer to the same one object... and they each have a _reference_ to that one object.  With a primitive type (string, number, boolean), the component gets its own copy of the primitive value in the constructor.  Any change you make to the primitive `name` property in the service is unrelated to any change you make to primitive `name` property in the component.

Comment: "If you change `name` in `NameService` you've got a different instance in the service and your components."  Even if you don't change the value, the component gets its own `name` primitive property in the constructor.  The initial value of this new primitive property is the value of the `name` property in the service, at the time of the assignment.  The point I'm trying to make is that with primitive types, you never have the same "instance".  One with reference types can you get two (or more) things referencing the same instance.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the solution provided by Günter is the best one.

That said, you must be aware that Angular2 services are singleton that take place into a tree of injectors. This means that:

- if you define your service at the application level (within the second parameter of the `bootstrap` method), the instance can be share by all elements (components and service).
- if you define your service at the component level (within the `providers` attribute), the instance will be specific to the component and its sub components.

For more details of such aspect, you can have a look at the "Hierarchical Dependency Injection" doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Hope it helps you,
Thierry