# Angular 2 EventEmitter performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm working on web-app based on Angular 2. In Angular 1 we had two-way data-bindings, so services could be easily connected with page data using $scope (if we change something in service, data will be automatically updated).

In Angular 2 we have EventEmitter, I thought it's like Angular 1's $scope.$broadcast, so there could be performance issues with this.

What about performance of EventEmitters? Do they slow down application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events emitted by `EventEmitter` don't bubble and also don't broadcast.  `EventEmitters` are for binding from child to parent only.

For broadcasting use shared services.

See also
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service
- [updating variable changes in components from a service with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)

Comment: Is there any performance benchmarks? In particular, how many EventEmitters effort app's performance?

Comment: I think `EventEmitters` are no burden for performance. They are (at least currently - might change in the future) `Observable` where an emitted event calls a callback on the subscribers. Events emitted by an `EventEmitter` can invoke Angulars change detection. It depends on your application and components how much work is actually to do when change detection is invoked. For example if you use `OnPush` then this might be cheap. With the default (`CheckAlways`) this can become pretty expensive.