# Angular 2: Application freezing when model is changed from select input

Tags: typescript, angular

In an Angular 2 application I am writing, I have a `select` element that is bound to a field in the controller via `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="dateInfo.year" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let year of getYearList()" [value]="year">{{year}}</option> 
</select>
```

`dateInfo` is a property in the controller that refers to a `DateInfo` object contained in a service called `DateService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class DateService {
  public dateInfo: DateInfo = {
    year: 2016
  }
}
```

The `DateInfo` object itself is a simple Typescript interface that just stores the year:

```
export interface DateInfo {
  year: number
}
```

The reason I am using this interface is to propagate changes to `year` to all components that use `DateService`, as per [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2).

For some reason, when the model is changed from the `select` element, the whole application freezes (tested in Chrome and Edge). I have made a plunker to illustrate the problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RvFqEpAsPEv4qPftFpaj?p=preview).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `getYearList()` returning a new array instance for every call. Every time Angulars change detection runs it detects a change because it gets a new array every time.
I wonder why you didn't get a "expression has changed since it was last checked thought"

Caching the result fixes the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/UKA35jIa9v6jFfrbJJuz?p=preview

This why it's usually bad practice to call methods from the template. Rather assign the result of a method call to a property and bind to this property instead.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well, but my goal is to generate a new year list every time `year` is changed so that `year` is in the middle of the list. The `getYearList()` method must return a new array every time `year` is changed.

Comment: I see, didn't investigate close properly. http://plnkr.co/edit/UKA35jIa9v6jFfrbJJuz?p=preview