# Angular : How to Manipulate an @Input / local variable in component directly from a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to manipulate the value of some local variables from the service which a component calls .

Yes , it can be done by subscribing(in component) to an Observable (in service) but i don't want to add anything in the component .

[updating variable changes in components from a service with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2/34714574#34714574)

which proposes this :

```
component {
     service.subject.subscribe (_=>{--do stuff here --})
} 
Service {
     subject() -- An observable --
}
```

I want the service to be responsible for setting some of my local variables (in component) .

Something like this :

Service -- > Call some component' variable and set it !

Can this be done ? If yes then how ?

Comment: please show some code...and what you have tried so far?

Comment: i will edit the question and add the related code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of using services is to make them independent and reusable. So your idea of having a service to modify the properties of a component introduces tight coupling between the service and component.

If you still want to do this, then create a setter on this service and invoke it from your component passing the reference to the component instance, e.g.

```
myService.setComponent(this);
```

Then you'll be able to modify properties of the component from the service. But again, I wouldn't recommend going this route.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer Yakov . Yes true , it will lead to tightly coupled entities . What i actually plan to do with this is to create a Component Manipulator service specifically for this which other services would use .
Basically what i am creating is some modules which by default takes care of some redundant stuff like showing 'Http request related Errors' without making the component write for it (Choice).

Comment: If you're going to proceed this route, create an interface declaring a method setErrors() and have each of your components implement it so your service will invoke the same method on each component. This will somewhat reduce the tight coupling.