# Change of Global Variable in one component Not reflected in other component in angular2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

In my header component I am declaring a variable `this.userFullName = this.globalService.userFullName;` & then I am using this variable userFullName in my header template . Now when I change my global variable  **userFullName** from another component (Counsellor Component) `this.globalService.userFullName = "Rob"` , this change not getting reflected into header template.Why so ? Any alternate solution for implementing this would also be helpful.

Comment: how are you using globalService in both the component ? 
have you included in separately  in providers for both ? , if yes , then it wont work. IF possible can you share the @component decorative for both and constructor definition as well.

Comment: For Header Component Component Decorator``@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})``  and constructor definition ``constructor(private globalService : GlobalService ,private router: Router) {
      this.userFullName = this.globalService.userFullName;   
}``   ;  for cousellor  ``@Component({
  selector: 'app-counsellor',
  templateUrl: './counsellor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counsellor.component.scss']
})``  and constructor definition  ``constructor(private globalService : GlobalService)``

Comment: you can refer this question , it provide exact answer to your question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2

Comment: I am using **Header Component** inside **Counsellor Component** ; So I think I should Reload Header after updating the **userFullName** Value .How to reload component  ?

Comment: you dont need to reload the component if you use observable to subscribe for the value , read the first answer in the link , I think it should solve your problem.

Comment: I went through this article [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)  and it solved my problem Thanks @priteshagrawal for your useful suggestion.