# Angular 2: Making a "global parameters service" and subscribing to its parameters

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm working on an Angular 2 app, where I want to store some "global variables" (state) across different components. This can be the user's choice of `year` and `customerId` etc. All components need to access these, for use in `GET` calls to the API/backend.

I have implemented router parameters, so it is possible to pass parameters into a component this way, but I find this easier to work with than having to maintain state by forwarding parameters through the router on every click. Hope this makes sense.

Anyway, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2) question on StackOverflow, I've set up the following `service`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

interface params {
    year: string;
    customerId: number;
};

@Injectable()
export class ParameterService {

    // initial (test) values:
    p: params = {
        year: "2017",
        customerId: 101
    };

    constructor() {}
}
```

This seems to work, two ways, allowing my components to get and set parameters like this:

```
    // get global value
    this.year = this._parameterService.p['year'];

    // set global value
    this._parameterService.p['year'] = "2018";
```

And data binding works, too. This is due to `p` being a class (object), rather than just accessing `string` `year` directly, as I understand it. If I change the `year` value from `component1`, then `component2` (below) will reflect the change:

```
  <h1>Year = {{this._parameterService.p['year']}}</h1>
```

All I need to do is inject the `ParameterService` into any component that needs it, and I'm done. **However, I can't figure out how to extend this such that a component will *reload* (execute another `GET` call) with the changed parameter.**

For router parameters, a component "subscribes" to the `params` in its `ngOnInit` method, causing it to "refresh" whenever a route changes:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.customerId = params['customerId'];
        this.year = params['year'];

        this.resetComponentState(); // based on new parameter this time
    }); 
}

resetComponentState(): void { 
    this._otherService.getDataFromApi(this.year)
        .then(
        myData => this.myData = myData,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing based on the `ParameterService`? Is it possible to somehow "bind" `this.year` with `this._parameterService.p['year']` in `resetComponentState()`? Btw, I *have* tried doing just that, but to no effect.

**UPDATE**
here is the full component which I want to refresh on parameter change (not just router parameter change):

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyData} from './mydata';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { OtherService } from './other.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { ParameterService } from '../parameter.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/test/test.component.html'
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    subscription: any;
    customerId: string;

    // set getter as a property on the variable `year`:
    ////year: string;
    get year(): string {
      console.log("test.component.get()");
      const value = this._parameterService.p['year'] + "";
      // Any other code you need to execute when the data is changed here
      this.getDataFromApi();
      return value;
    }

    private sub: any;

    errorMessage: string;
    data: MyData[];
    constructor(private _otherService: OtherService,
        private _parameterService: ParameterService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

    getDataFromApi() {

        // store route parameters in Local Storage
        // if none found, try reading from Local Storage
        if (this.customerId == null)
            this.customerId = this._localStorageService.get('customerId') + "";
        //if (this.year== null)
        //    this.year = this._localStorageService.get('year') + "";            

        this._localStorageService.set('customerId', this.customerId);
        //this._localStorageService.set('year', this.year);

        // try getting YEAR (not customerId, yet) from getter
        this._otherService.getDataFromApi(this.customerId, this.year)
            .then(
            data => this.data = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    getData(): void{
        this.data = this._otherService.getData();
    }

    resetComponentState(): void {
        this.getDataFromApi();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.customerId = params['customerId'];
            //this.year = params['year'];

            this.resetComponentState(); // based on new parameter this time
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As for generic global service, I would suggest to have both get/set and observable for each variable, this makes it flexible enough. I cannot recommend to do this for route params. They are not global, they are specific to current route. You've already got `route.params` observable and `route.snapshot.params` object for ActivatedRoute, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm overcomplicating things? Point is, some component has a date picker, so if the user changes year I need some mechanism to update year in all other active components. This can't be done through route, as far as I know. So that calls for a global service? If I understand you, you're saying "do use a global service, but don't tie it to the route parameters. You've already got these covered by route observable." My point is that I also want to support "direct links" to components through route. But then I could use `year_param` or something in the route, not same variable `year`?

Comment: So invoking route, `mycomponent/2015/102` could be matched by route observable, but go into variables `year_param` and `id_param`, respectively. This would then not conflict with getter on variable `year`. And, if the user does pass in year and id directly in the URL, so to speak, I could reflect this app-wide by setting (storing) values in the global service, through the setters. I'd just have to ensure that doesn't result in a duplicated refresh of the component (first from route params, and then second time from global params changing).

Comment: *do use a global service, but don't tie it to the route parameters. You've already got these covered by route observable* - yes, I guess that's what I'm saying. From what I see, a 'service' looks and acts like a model, so I would call it a model. It clearly should be decoupled from the router. Can you provide an example of 'a duplicated refresh of the component' if such problem exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use getters and setters. Something like this:

```
// get global value
get year() {
   const value = this._parameterService.p['year'];
   // Any other code you need to execute when the data is changed here
   this.getDataFromApi();
   return value;
}

set year(value) {
   this._parameterService.p['year'] = value;
}
```

I have a blog post about this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

And a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had a look, but I can't see how this helps me trigger a new (refreshed) call to the API when the parameters change. Data binding (showing the value in the template), however, works already. I've updated the question with the full component. Should I invoke the `getter` somehow in the call to `getDataFromApi()`?

Comment: Or should the `getter` invoke `getDataFromApi` (as per your comment, "any other code you need to execute when the data is changed here")?

Comment: Yes, the second one. When the data is checked, Angular's change detection will recognize the change and re-retrieve the value, calling the getter. You can then add any code you need there that should be executed when the data is changed. Give it a try ...

Comment: Thanks again, I did try it but nothing happened. Surely, there is something I'm getting wrong. First, Typescript won't let me define the getter without a `return` value: `a 'get' accessor must return a value`. So, I just `return value` (and type the getter to `get year(): string`). When I change (set) the parameter, using `this._parameterService.p['year'] = value;` from some other component (say, `menuComponent`), the value is changed in the `TestComponent` view (HTML), but the closest I can get to something working is a `RangeError` where `get` and `getDataFromApi` recurse until crash.

Comment: Well -- something did happen, not just what I wanted ;) I've tried updating the example (TestController) with the code.

Comment: Did you try the plunker?

Comment: Yes, of course :) But that demonstrates setting the value in one component, and seeing it update in the view of another component (as far as I could understand)? What I'm looking for (and forgive me if I'm just not seeing your point) is a way to set a value (in the `ParameterService`) from one controller, with the effect of "refreshing" another component. I.e. the other component immediately *re-does* its API GET call, and updates its entire HTML. Please note, **both** these components are shown/active at the same time in the application (as in, menu and report components).

Comment: I tried to fork and modify your Plunker, placing component `a` with a `menu` selector, alongside component `b`. I couldn't save the edits, so here is my modified `a` controller: https://pastebin.com/szqugSJq (I also added `<menu></menu>` to `app.ts`). **Since it works there, in the Plunker, but not in my app, this must mean my app contains some other code which causes the problems/conflict (read, crash).** Thanks again for your help!