# Angular2 Unit Tests - Test Subject ( watch on variable from service)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I have a watch in one of my components which watches a variable in a service (so a Subject). (I got the implementation idea of this here: [updating variable changes in components from a service with angular2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714462/updating-variable-changes-in-components-from-a-service-with-angular2)  However, now my whole tests in the component are failing because I need to mock this somehow but I don't know how and I could not find any answer to that. That's my code:

**Component where I watch the change of the variable in the constructor:**

```
  constructor(private updateService: UpdateService) {

    // check if intents are updated in the updateService through upload component, if yes update training status
    this.intentsSubscription = updateService.intentsChange.subscribe((value) => this.initTrainingStatus());
  }
```

**Service where the Variable-Change is triggered:**

```
 public intentsChange: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();
   .....

    public updateIntents(appId: number) {
        this.requestsService.getAllIntents(appId)
          .subscribe(intents => {
            this.setIntents(intents);
            this.intentsChange.next(intents);
          });
      }
```

**Tests of the component which are currently failing because:**

> TypeError: updateService.intentsChange.subscribe is not a function

```
describe('TrainButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: TrainButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TrainButtonComponent>;

  let mockUpdateService;
  let intentsChange: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();


  beforeEach(async(() => {
      intentsChange() {
        return Subject.of({});
      }
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ],
      declarations: [ TrainButtonComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UpdateService, useValue: mockUpdateService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrainButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockUpdateService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UpdateService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Does anyone know how to fix that Error so my Tests are actually running through again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intentsChange` what you declared in `beforeEach` do nothing.

All what you need is to correctly mock `updateService` in before each:

```
updateService = TestBed.get(UpdateService); // or somehow else, as you wish
spyOn(updateService, 'intentsChange').and.returnValue(Observable.of(<SomeValueHere>)); // <-- here is main point
```

Now check that `this.initTrainingStatus()` was called. This will work.

Don't forget to `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'` somewhere at the top.